# Parsing JSON with jQuery, retrieving two variables.

Tags: javascript, json

I have a online JSON file that looks something like this:

```
[
{
"j": 0,
"i": 0,
"DepartureTime": "\/Date(1331667480000+0100)\/",
"ArrivalTime": "\/Date(1331668860000+0100)\/",
"Remarks": [],
"TravelStages": [
  {
    "ID": 0,
    "DepartureStop": {
      "WalkingDistance": 0,
      "ArrivalTime": null,
      "AlightingAllowed": false,
      "DepartureTime": null,
      "BoardingAllowed": false,
      "RealTimeStop": true,
      "Rank": 0,
      "Lines": null,
      "StopPoints": [
        {
          "ID": 1,
          "Name": "1",
          "X": 608127,
          "Y": 6645778
        }
      ],
      "Zone": "1",
      "X": 608133,
      "Y": 6645768,
      "ID": 2300500,
      "Name": "Visperud (i Solheimvn)",
      "District": "Lørenskog",
      "Type": 0,
      "Stops": [],
      "ShortName": "VIS"
    }]
```

What I want is the grab out the **DepartureTime** and **ArrivalTime**, I've seen some examples on how to parse the flickr JSON. But I can't figure out how I can parse this. I also want to store the **departureTime** and **arrivalTime** in two separate variables since the content of this two is a time measured in milliseconds since 1970. Can somebody give me a hint on how a can do this, am totally new to Javascript/JSON

Comment: That isn't valid JSON according to JSONLint.com

Comment: it's a part of my JSON file, but its too long for posting her.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have jQuery in your project? If so, you can easily parse the JSON string like this

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(theJsonText);
alert(obj.DepartureTime);
```

If not, I suggest including the JSON library ([link](http://www.json.org/js.html)) and using that.

Comment: But how can I specify the URL? just replacing the parameter? :)

Comment: what URL? you didn't mention you don't have the string. then you'll need AJAX to get it... please clarify your question: you don't want to parse JSON, you want to *download* and parse JSON.

Comment: He says he has an online JSON file, therefore needing to download it.

Comment: As my first sentence says: _"I have a online JSON file that looks something like this"_ So I need to download it and parse it. But this file is constantly updated, so in this case I can't download it just one time, I guess.

Comment: yeah, but e.g. many PHP scripts directly dump the json into the generated javascript, so it wasn't quite clear. I'll write an example below...

Comment: If you don't have the JSON in a string, you'll need to get it using `$.getJSON(url, function(obj){ alert(obj.DepartureTime); });`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, assuming that your json file is in `jsonfile.json`

```
$.getJSON('jsonfile.json', function(data){
    alert("Departure Time: "+ data.DepartureTime);
    alert("Arrival Time: "+ data.ArrivalTime);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON('http://your.domain.example/path/to/file.json', function(data) {
  departure_time=data.DepartureTime;
  arrival_time=data.ArrivalTime;
  do_something_with(departure_time,arrival_time);
});
```

then `do_something_with(str,str)` would be called with the strings `"\/Date(1331667480000+0100)\/"` and `"\/Date(1331668860000+0100)\/"` (in your example).
you'll still have to convert the dates to numbers, e.g. by running:

```
parsed_date=new Date(parseInt(input_string.substr(7)));
//substr(7) cuts after "\/Date(", and parseInt ignores ")\/"
//but I don't know how it handles "+0100"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats an array containing objects, so you should be able to just set some vars equal to the properties of the first index. to use it like an object, it needs to be parsed.. so either eval(thatJson) or $.parseJSON(thatJson) and then iterate through it.

```
var responses = [
{
"j": 0,
"i": 0,
"DepartureTime": "\/Date(1331667480000+0100)\/",
"ArrivalTime": "\/Date(1331668860000+0100)\/",
"Remarks": [],
...
}];

var dep = responses[0].DepartureTime;
var arr = responses[0].ArrivalTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to JSONLint.com, your string isn't valid JSON. That is, however, a different issue than what your question asks for.

Assuming a valid subset of your string

```
var a = '[{"j": 0,"i": 0,"DepartureTime": "/Date(1331667480000+0100)/",      "ArrivalTime": "/Date(1331668860000+0100)/","Remarks": []}]';

var obj = $.parseJSON(a);
console.log(obj[0].ArrivalTime);​
```